# Debugging Maven build in Eclipse 2022

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Aim: I have a Maven application that does not have any JUnit testcases. I want to debug the app.

Setup: I choose the Maven plugin maven.surefire.debug. I have specified the plugin details in the Run-->DebugConfigurations. After adding breakpoints, when I run the app in debug mode, rather than Listening at default port 5005, the app runs to completion.

Query: How to make the app listen at port 5005 and eventually stop at breakpoint? Please help me in resolving the issue.

[image: Debug Configurations]

Comment: A Maven run (not debug) configuration with `maven.surefire.debug` set to `true` and the goal `test` should since Eclipse 2022-03 be enough to start remote debugging on the port that is printed on the console. See also my video here: https://youtu.be/GnNnQY5ujFg?t=370

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. As suggested by you, I did Maven Run rather than Maven Debug.  But, still remote debugging is not started. What could be the reason.

Comment: You might try it with the [sample project shown in the video](https://github.com/howlger/Eclipse-IDE-improvements-videos/tree/2022-03/sample_code/Eclipse%202022-03%20Improvements). If it works, it's something of your project; if not, it's something of your Eclipse IDE. See also https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#1200

Comment: Thanks @howlger. With the sample project, the application displays "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005" and stops at breakpoints.

Comment: I see the sample project has Junit5 testcases. Whereas, one of my application has Junit4 testcases. So, my queries are; does maven.surefire.debug=true and the goal "test" works with Junit5 only? How do I debug a Maven application which does NOT have any Junit testcases?